# how to change background color of navigation tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"></button>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Portfolio</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my code. How can I change the tab color when a user hovers over a tab? I want the color to be green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navbar-nav li:hover{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Will target only the `<li>` tags within the `.navbar-nav` class. `:hover` is a pseudo selector.

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked!

Comment: im sorry im super new here on stackoverflow. how do you "accept" answers? nvm i got it.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
selector:hover { 
 background: color;
}
```